# Playing a single midi note from gs_instruments in iOS / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, ios9, midi

I'm looking to play a single midi note on an iOS app using Swift.

Here's what I have so far, but unfortunately this crashes with an error.

```
func initAudio(){

    let engine = AVAudioEngine()
    self.sampler = AVAudioUnitSampler()
    engine.attachNode(self.sampler!)
    engine.connect(self.sampler!, to: engine.outputNode, format: nil)

    guard let soundbank = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("gs_instruments", withExtension: "dls") else {

        print("Could not initalize soundbank.")
        return
    }

    let melodicBank:UInt8 = UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultMelodicBankMSB)
    let gmHarpsichord:UInt8 = 6
    do {

        try self.sampler!.loadSoundBankInstrumentAtURL(soundbank, program: gmHarpsichord, bankMSB: melodicBank, bankLSB: 0)

    }catch {
        print("An error occurred \(error)")
        return
    }

    self.sampler!.startNote(60, withVelocity: 64, onChannel: 0)
}
```

Here's the error message:

```
Unable to start playing the low note. Error code: -10867 'ç’ˇˇ'
2015-11-25 15:10:07.419 Demo[774:139850] 15:10:07.418 ERROR:    [0x19eaf4000] AVAudioUnitMIDIInstrument.mm:103: -[AVAudioUnitMIDIInstrument startNote:withVelocity:onChannel:]: error -10867
2015-11-25 15:10:07.419 Demo[774:139850] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'error -10867'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

The `AVAudioEngine` needs to be *started* before usage (`error -10867` means "not initialized").

Add `try engine.start()` inside the Do-Catch:

```
do {
    try engine.start()
    try self.sampler!.loadSoundBankInstrumentAtURL(soundbank, program: gmHarpsichord, bankMSB: melodicBank, bankLSB: 0)
}catch {
    print("An error occurred \(error)")
    return
}
```

---

#### About the error code

In your error message there's this line:

> 2015-11-25 15:10:07.419 Demo[774:139850] 15:10:07.418 ERROR:    [0x19eaf4000] AVAudioUnitMIDIInstrument.mm:103: -[AVAudioUnitMIDIInstrument startNote:withVelocity:onChannel:]: error -10867

We see that the emitter of the error code is `AVAudioUnitMIDIInstrument`, which inherits from `AVAudioUnit`: these things come from the "AudioUnit" framework which is located in OS X's System folder.

AudioUnit 's error codes are defined in this header file:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AUComponent.h

The part that is relevant for us:

```
CF_ENUM(OSStatus) {
    kAudioUnitErr_InvalidProperty           = -10879,
    kAudioUnitErr_InvalidParameter          = -10878,
    kAudioUnitErr_InvalidElement            = -10877,
    kAudioUnitErr_NoConnection              = -10876,
    kAudioUnitErr_FailedInitialization      = -10875,
    kAudioUnitErr_TooManyFramesToProcess    = -10874,
    kAudioUnitErr_InvalidFile               = -10871,
    kAudioUnitErr_UnknownFileType           = -10870,
    kAudioUnitErr_FileNotSpecified          = -10869,
    kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported        = -10868,
    kAudioUnitErr_Uninitialized             = -10867,
    kAudioUnitErr_InvalidScope              = -10866,
    kAudioUnitErr_PropertyNotWritable       = -10865,
    kAudioUnitErr_CannotDoInCurrentContext  = -10863,
    kAudioUnitErr_InvalidPropertyValue      = -10851,
    kAudioUnitErr_PropertyNotInUse          = -10850,
    kAudioUnitErr_Initialized               = -10849,
    kAudioUnitErr_InvalidOfflineRender      = -10848,
    kAudioUnitErr_Unauthorized              = -10847,
    kAudioComponentErr_InstanceInvalidated  = -66749,
};
```

Comment: Thanks thats what it was. Out of interest, how did you find out what that error code meant?

Comment: You're welcome. I've added an explanation about the error code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should still get this to work by connecting the sampler to the AVAudioEngine graph, ie calling AVAudioEngine.attachNode.

The reason this fails specifically is that the engine reference contained inside the sampler is not yet initialized. Calling attachNode does that, and thus it is ok to call startEngine later on.